# Nuxt3 how to prerender all routes without any server side files

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, prerender, nuxt3

I'm trying to use nuxt3 to prerender my entire website, without having to rely on a server. I am looking to just get the html file alongside JS & css files.

However, even with this config, it still outputs server side files.

```js
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  nitro: {
    prerender: { crawlLinks: true },
  },
})
```

Docs: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use `npm run generate` instead of `npm run build`. As simple as that.

You can remove your crawlLinks config as crawling is defaulted with the `generate` command and it generates a full static site.

Answer (score 0):

With this config you should see your entire website as static files, prerendered and generated at the `.output/public` folder.

Watch out for this in the terminal upon building:

```
...
✔ Generated public .output/public                                                                                                                                                            nitro 12:33:32 PM
ℹ Initializing prerenderer                                                                                                                                                                   nitro 12:33:32 PM
ℹ Prerendering 1 initial routes with crawler                                                                                                                                                 nitro 12:33:32 PM
  ├─ / (18ms)
...
```

You can basically ignore all other server side files that were generated for you, because the entire website is pre-rendered.